# Can one upload files using Python SimpleHTTPServer or cgi?

Tags: python, file-upload, webserver, cgi, simplehttpserver

I would like to have a simple web page on which user can upload files. What would be the simplest way to do it.

I know how to start `SimpleHTTPServer` but I do not know how I can upload files using `SimpleHTTPServer`. I do not even know if it is possible.

I found some code for uploading files using cgi but if I execute this code in the command line it just prints me HTML code on the screen.

Comment: `SimpleHTTPServer` is plain simple to the extent that it does not provide any ftp (upload) support.

Comment: [Here](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/pythonwebserver.php) is another exmaple. Also [here](https://code.google.com/p/python-simple-fileserver/).

Comment: Can you tell us how are you executing the code and what is the output when you upload a file from browser?

Answer (score 4):

I am still new to Python and have tried using the same code you added to your post. The only problem with it is that it only allows for single file upload.
I wanted to upload multiple files at a time.

Using the still available code found [here](https://gist.github.com/UniIsland/3346170), you can replace the `deal_post_data` method with the following:

```
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(
    fp=self.rfile,
    headers=self.headers,
    environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST'})

    self.send_response(200)
    self.end_headers()
    
    saved_fns = ""
    
    try:
        if isinstance(form['file'], list):
            for f in form['file']:
                print f.filename
                saved_fns = saved_fns + ", " + f.filename
                self.save_file(f)
                self.wfile.write(f.value)
        else:
            f = form['file']
            self.save_file(f)
            saved_fns = saved_fns + f.filename
            self.wfile.write(f.value)
        return (True, "File(s) '%s' upload success!" % saved_fns)
    except IOError:
        return (False, "Can't create file to write, do you have permission to write?")
```

Then add the following function to save the uploaded file:

```
def save_file(self, file):
    outpath = os.path.join("", file.filename)
    with open(outpath, 'wb') as fout:
        shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, fout, 100000)
```

Finally, change the html form to allow for multiple files to be uploaded at a time using the `multiple` tag in the inserted HTML.

I just finished testing this and it works fine.

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 3):

Yes, SimpleHTTPServer can receive http uploads with the correct request handler.

Basicly you need to define a do_POST method where a form or something similar uploads the data. the upload is then readble from self.rfile.

```
class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
     # ...
     def do_POST(self):
         for line in self.rfile:
             # do something with the line
             print line
```

of course if you want to upload from a browser you need to have a form somewhere that posts to the http server:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://hostname.of.server:8080/">
  <input name="file" type="file"/>
  <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

More details in particular how to parse the raw data from the form-data can be found in the links posted as comments to the question.

Comment: can you post the link?

Comment: I think i wanted to write "the links posted as comments to the question", but i don't remember really.